# Asus transformer is not visible through adb

Tags: android, windows-7, adb, transformer-model

I have a problem with adb on Windows 7 and Asus Transformer (ISC, 4.0.3)

adb devices shows empty list.

I've installed Asus PC Suit, USB debugging is switched on. On Linux everything works fine.

Comment: I guess you've installed the usb drivers from the suite? (or that they're included)

Comment: Well actually it is for an Android developer :) adb is used to deploy and debug Android applications on an attached device.

Answer (score 0):

if the usb package of android doesn't work , try this :
http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=20&s=16&m=Eee+Pad+Transformer+TF101&os=32

also , make sure the usb cable is short enough . some devices and some computers have problems with too long usb cables . in addition , try different usb ports .

Comment: I already have this drive and USB cable is short.

Comment: have you enabled the debugging feature on the device itself?

Comment: Yes it is, according to his question. And it seems to work on Linux already, too.

Comment: can you try other PCs with this OS ? also , if nothing helps , you can always root your device and use an app to use adb via wifi , such as "adb wireless".